# Optimize quantifiers and for in Z3py

Tags: python, z3, first-order-logic

so I'm lloking for a way to simplify the following code in Z3py because every time I want to check this assertion (on my own computer or on http://rise4fun.com/z3py/ ) it just timed out so I think there could be fastest ways to do.

```
Task = Datatype('Task')
Task.declare("cons",("num", IntSort()),("order",IntSort()),("arrival",IntSort()))
Task = Task.create()
order = Task.order
num = Task.num
x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')
s = Solver()
tasks = (Task.cons(0,0,0),\
     Task.cons(0,1,0),\
     Task.cons(0,2,0),\
     Task.cons(0,3,0),\
     Task.cons(1,0,1),\
     Task.cons(1,1,1),\
     Task.cons(1,2,1),\
     Task.cons(2,0,3),\
     Task.cons(2,1,3),\
     Task.cons(2,2,3),\
     Task.cons(2,3,3),\
     Task.cons(2,4,3),\
     Task.cons(3,0,1),\
     Task.cons(3,1,1))
p1 = Function('p1',IntSort(),Task)
p2 = Function('p2',IntSort(),Task)
order = And([Exists([x,y],Or(And(p1(x)==t1,p1(y)==t2,If(num(t1)==num(t2),Implies(x<y,order(t1)<order(t2)),True)),\
                         And(p1(x)==t1,p2(y)==t2,If(num(t1)==num(t2),Implies(x<y,order(t1)<order(t2)),True)),\
                         And(p2(x)==t1,p1(y)==t2,If(num(t1)==num(t2),Implies(x<y,order(t1)<order(t2)),True)),\
                         And(p2(x)==t1,p2(y)==t2,If(num(t1)==num(t2),Implies(x<y,order(t1)<order(t2)),True))))\
             for t1 in tasks for t2 in tasks])
s.add(order)
```

As you can seen it is really a big formula but I didn't found a way to make it smaller... The objective is to make sure that every parts of a task are in order even if they are processed by different processors (p1 or p2)

Thanks a lot in advance if you can help me (even just a hint that could help me to change that formula would be great)

edit : I just tested that constraint alone and it works,it give strange results but still works, but I still need it to work with others constraints so if you can help me to optimize it you're welcome.

Comment: You can partially evaluate some of the expressions. Z3 should simplify them for you as well, but it does not hurt to do this when you have the information handy. Taking your example I get the following version with pre-processing: 
http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/29z
However, it indicates that the constraints are not written the way you intend them: the last conjunction in each of the disjunctions is the same and the conditions on p1(x) and p2(x) can also be re-distributed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will try to simplify it, but I still have a hard time when trying to use def (I always mess up my code...) so I try to avoid it, but I think I should stop doing so... If you want to see my actual code (all constraint added) it is here : http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/77sl

Comment: Thanks to your help I was able to figure out how to change my code, now I just have to find why it is so long to give me a solution with my latest version which allow me to change the number of processors: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/F3mL .

But the version where I can't change their number works really fine and gives me good results : http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/zTxE